# Is there a bug with Vagrant? How exactly does one successfully use Vagrant on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have pored through pages of Stack Overflow and find tons of answers that do not solve my inability to get "vagrant up" successfully...well, up on my Mac. Here is what happens:

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MBP-3 ~ $ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32                                                                       [ruby-2.3.0]
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
ldco2016@DCortes-MBP-3 ~ $ vagrant up                                                                                             [ruby-2.3.0]
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant works properly on Mac OS X. The problem you described does seem to be a bug in Vagrant, nor your mistake.

Vagrant does not really perform complicated tasks related to virtual machines itself, but sets the options and runs other programs.

In this case Vagrant ordered VirtualBox to create and start a new virtual machine and then periodically checked that machine's status to connect when it got into a "running" state. Instead Vagrant was informed that the machine had been powered off:

> The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
>   to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
>   'poweroff' state.

This indicates a problem with your VirtualBox (installation, settings, resources) and you should look there.

First run the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager, right-click on the machine entry and choose "Show log..."; check if you can start the machine yourself; check the memory and CPU settings in VirtualBox.

---

Side note: Sometimes a tweak in `Vagrantfile` for OS X is required (mainly for disk sharing between the guest and host), but this is not the case with `hashicorp/precise32`. Using the two commands you ran, the machine started properly on El Capitan, Vagrant 1.8.4, VirtualBox 5.0.16.

Comment: So it seems when I go into Virtual box, I can't even get it to power on manually and so Vagrant can't get it to power up. Any suggestions? I mean if I delete and reinstall virtualbox, I don't want to get this problem again. Could it be an issue with a certain version of VB? I currently have version 4.2.36.

Comment: So apparently, I had downloaded version 1.8.1 several weeks ago and the most current version of Vagrant is 1.8.5. When I updated the version, it now plays nice with my VirtualBox 5.1. This is a gotcha because the Vagrant error messages kept saying the problem must be with the VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

`hashicorp/*` are pretty old boxes (generally older than 2 years).

You would want to use `ubuntu/precise32` in your case, which are the official boxed maintained by folks from hashicorp